# Can docker-compose / dockerfile access host env vars at build time?

Tags: docker

Is it possible for a dockerfile / docker compose file to access the host env vars at build time when running `docker-compose build app` or do you have to manually pass them into the build command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Environment variables from the host that you want to use at build time would need to be passed into the build command with the `--build-arg` flag described [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/compose_build/).